# Playframework - GSPs and taglibs?

Tags: grails, playframework, template-engine, playframework-2.0

Is it possible to use the Grails GSP engine as the template engine in Play?

Including `TagLibraries` and such?`

What is neccessary to make that stuff work?

( I prefer the HTML style tags over the Ruby style ( ugly annoying )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template engine is a pluggable system. For example, in Play 1.0 there is already the out of the box Groovy engine, the Scala engine within the Scala module, the Cambridge and Japid engines, also available as plugins.

For Play 2.0, there is already the Scala engine, and an implementation of the Groovy engine (I believe intended to be a plugin).

To answer your question of can it be done, the above clearly shows that it is possible, as others have done similar. To answer what is necessary, it depends on which platform you are targetting (Play 1 or 2), but there exists examples of both that you can follow to create your own module. I would highlight that Play 2.0 is not a stable release yet, so be cautious and prepare for some things to change over the next month or so, until a final release is issued.

Comment: When is Play 2.0 planned to be released? Another question I have is, when developing in Play, is it 100% Java, or static, except for the template engine? Why I am asking is to know if it  can even be considered in a Enterprise solution where stabiliy is a top priority. With dynamic language, you kind of loose control. I am sure it is possible to write dynamic code in Playframework, but my opinion is that it should remain 100% Java ( the glue is a different matter ) so that all compilation errors, refactoring and such will still be bulletproof as they are in Java and the supporting IDE's.

Comment: Play 2.0 is scheduled for some time in March at last update. Play is 100% static, except for template as you say.